# Referencing a table in different workbook using IndexMatch or Vlookup only works when WB open

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 2013 64bit, win 7

Goal = Use a Table name reference from a closed workbook in formula with Index Match (or vLookup if necessary workaround).

Seems simple enough, but none of these are working when I recalculate after closing the referenced Tables workbook. This one should work and I tried a lot of other things but no success. (EDIT: My understanding is this is impossible to reference a table in a closed workbook? Going to move on to bottom solution)

Works only when workbook is open, when closed it shows #REF!
`=INDEX('C:\Vendors.xlsm'!VendName[[#All],[Qty]],MATCH(A1,'C:\Vendors.xlsm'!VendName[[#All],[SKU]],0))`

With vlookup, same thing, it only works when workbook is opened.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'C:\Vendors.xlsm'!VendName[#All],3,0)
```

However if I use named range instead of table it will work!

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'C:\Vendors.xlsm'!VendName,3,0)
```

So why not use name range with Index Match? I couldnt figure out how to tell Index match to use a specific column of a named range like I do a table. ie follow the table name with [[#All],[SKU]]. Also I find it hard to believe you cant reference a table in a closed workbook, I must be missing the proper solution.

What am I doing wrong in the first formula so that it will not work when table WB is closed? And how would I use a named range but tell it to reference the 3rd row of a named range within Index Match formula?

Update: I believe I need to ditch the external table and use the external regular NameRanges only, but how do I reference a name range/2nd column.

```
=INDEX(ExcelFile.xlsx!NamedRange,MATCH(F4,ExcelFile.xlsx!NamedRange,0))
```

In this example, the Named range is 5 columns wide, how do I tell it to match with the 1st row and reference the 3rd. Ie  =INDEX(ExcelFile.xlsx!NamedRange,Row(2) or something...

I cant figure out how to tell Index match to use a specific column of a named range. In the below: Name Range refers to column A:D. Hardcode to match data from column 3 at the end there is perfectly fine. What make this formula fail though is the second use of NameRange. The formula needs to reference column B (2nd column of the range NameRange). How do I force that? Something like NameRange[Column2] (I made up the format to express the goal).

> =INDEX(NameRange,MATCH(H10,NameRange,0),3)

Comment: Check my comment to my answer below - you can create a new range that is equal to the 2nd column of your NamedRange, by using INDEX(NameRange,0,2). This creates a column with all rows of NameRange, and only the 2nd column. This can be used as your 'search range' for Match.

Answer (score 1):

You could perform an index(data_table,match1,match2), which pulls match1 by comparing the search term with the reference column, and which pulls match2 by comparing the search term with the reference row.

ie: Assume your reference column on the data table workbook is A:A. Assume your reference row (for headers) is 1:1.

Set 3 named ranges:

(1) A1:Z100 = "FullData" showing the full data table as a 2D range.
(2) A:A = "ItemIndex" showing only the reference column.
(3) 1:1 = "HeaderIndex" showing only the refrence row.

Your formula to reference this in an your results workbook would be:

```
=INDEX('C:\Vendors.xlsm'!FullData,MATCH($A1,'C:\Vendors.xlsm'!ItemIndex,0),MATCH("HEADER NAME TO MATCH",'C:\Vendors.xlsm'!HeaderIndex,0))
```

There may be some broader issues with using this to reference a closed book, but I'm not very familiar with that general process, so someone may have thoughts on a better way for you to do this overall. This answers your initial question to do it with your method, at least.

**EDIT**

As you have 20+ tables, and the headers are always in the same order, you can simply use your vlookup as proposed like this; will prevent you from needing to declare 3 Name Ranges for each tab; instead you will only need to create one Named Range per tab, like so:

```
=vlookup(A1,'C:\Vendors.xlsm'!FullData,5)
```

This hardcodes to pull in the 5th column as you said the headers are the same from table to table and don't change. To instead make it pull from the header you want, create a searching index row in your results tab (let's assume row 1 on sheet 2, with the search term for the header on cell B1):

```
    =vlookup(A1,'C:\Vendors.xlsm'!FullData,MATCH(B1,Sheet2!1:1,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the method however it doesnt seem to suit my needs. I would have to make 3 unique ranges for each of 20 tables (vendors), which lacks the flexibility and simplicity I am going for. Also their headers are in the same row with same values. I need to be able to do this with one Table name or NamedRange per vendor.

Comment: @Bryan two things: (1) you should include details like that when formulating your question - the more info you provide, the easier it is to see what might actually help you. (2) If your headers are the same, you won't need to create a header-Named-Range for each tab, you can just use a MATCH function for a single header tab that you create on your results workbook. You could even just hardcode a number if it would never change. See my Edit to solve this issue.

Comment: 1) Noted, thanks.
2) Yes this Vlookup is working with NamedRange, thanks for the flexible alternative but with my setup the hardcode will work.

However I realize you can NOT reference a table in a closed workbook this way. So I will stick with NameRange only. This is the best solution I have so far, but I'd like to try and make this work with Index match. (it is a huge setup and a lot of simultaneous calculations with it.) I am editing my question with more detail on this other solution problem.

Comment: I cant figure out how to tell Index match to use a specific column of a named range. In the below: Name Range refers to column A:D. Hardcode to match data from column 3 at the end there is perfectly fine. What make this formula fail though is the second use of NameRange. The formula needs to reference column B (2nd column of the range NameRange). How do I force that? Something like NameRange[Column2] (I made up the format to express the goal).

    =INDEX(NameRange,MATCH(H10,NameRange,0),3)

Comment: Actually, there's a handy feature of INDEX you might not know of: if you tell INDEX to pull the '0' column or the '0' row, it will actually pull all items in that column / row. So, INDEX(1:5,0,3) will give you the result C1:C5, because it pulls the 3rd column and all rows from your given search area of 1:5. You can then wrap that in your other function and use it as your "search column", like so: INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH("SEARCH TERM", INDEX(1:5,0,3),0)). This searches for the SEARCH TERM within C1:C5,  and gives you the result for that row from column A. Does that help?

Comment: No I did not know that, that is very useful thanks! Looks like I got the mission accomplished today, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I concluded the following:

1. Cannot reference tables in closed workbooks for Index Match and vLookup. Use simple Name Ranges.
2. Here is how to use Index Match with NameRanges that contain multiple columns. 
   =INDEX(NameRange,MATCH(H10,INDEX(NameRange,0,1),0),3)

The solution to being specific about a return value column for the first NameRange is to add that ending ,3) thus returning the value in the 3rd column.

The solution to being specific about the lookup column to match is instead of just putting the MATCH(A1,NameRange,. use MATCH(A1,INDEX(NameRange,0,1),... This tells it to use the first column in that Named Range.

This solutions allows you to write one formula for a standard table layout, and simply change the Name for each range and apply across. I then was able to use this with Indirect so that the formula throughout the sheet can reference a helper cell on top so it never has to be changed when adding more vendors.